# The Camera does not open up when I scan a QR code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a QR code scanner function  that does not open the camera. The scanner screen appears but I do not see the box with the line inside for scanning.

I have also added camera permissions in the Android manifest

Android Manifest Permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The Scanner Function is below

```
Future <void> scanqr() async {
      final qrCode = await scanner.scan();
     
        setState(() {
          this.qrCode = qrCode;
        });
}
```

Comment: try removing `android:required="false"` from manifeest file

Comment: I removed it but it does not work still

Comment: which is package your are using?

Comment: I am using `import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;`

Comment: @LefentseMphahlele any error shows in console?

Comment: I get a `cannot open camera “0” without camera permission` Error when I try to open a camera to scan a QR code